# How to access Raima DB using linux commands - Access and list tables

Tags: linux, raima

I am dealing with a legacy system which uses Raima as database manager. I want to be able to access the database using this type of management system . I am new to this and want to understand how it works and how can I do basic queries to this DB using linux commands. So for starters how can I access the DB and how can I list the tables within the DB?

Comment: yes.I did not find much info about this. Can you point me out some good links?

Comment: maybe I can be more specific on my question and go from there.

Comment: How about this? http://books.raima.com/rdme/11_0/PDFIDA.pdf

Comment: I have put that PDF in answer section so i can attract to many eye balls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While its useful let me put it here:

> [RDMe Interactive Database Access Utility Guide](http://books.raima.com/rdme/11_0/PDFIDA.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

There is some info about this here :

http://www.raima.com/sql-create-database/